# Openstack cinder volume resize does not reflect without a vm reboot

Tags: openstack, kvm, openstack-nova, openstack-cinder

When I extend a cinder volume which is "in-use" state, the volume gets extended but when I see inside the vm it does not show the extension it still shows the same size.
Only after a reboot the change shows inside the vm - windows disk management.
Is there a way to force this change, where I dont have to reboot the server and it shows the change on the fly.
The problem is we can not stop the IO on the disk, so can not really afford a reboot.
Any direction here, how to solve this problem. Thanks

Openstack version: Xena
KVM hypervisor

Comment: How could you extend a volume which is `in-use` state?

Answer (score 0):

- Add "qemu guest agent" app to windows image . try this document for the purpose of intalling guest agent in windows
  https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Qemu-guest-agent
- then activate guest agent via image properties

```
openstack image set IMG-UUID --property  hw_qemu_guest_agent=yes
```

hope this is helpull